# Addon to compare topology of two meshes

Tags: mesh, objects, add-on, topology

So I have say two meshes, A and B. In some plases, both meshes may have similar surfaces and in other cases they don't. Is there an addon to compare the meshes and determine to what degree they match. I know we can simply keep the two meshes on each other and look for extrusions but I am looking for something else, such as a procedure which can compare the faces, the orientation etc.

I have a (yet to be working) 3D camera system which will provide me with 3D models and I wanted to compare the meshes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30420/blender-for-science-is-it-possible-to-compare-2-meshes-for-their-resemblance

Comment: Are you asking about the existence of a Blender add on to do this? Otherwise, the development or existence of the procedure for determining the amount of similarity between two meshes is a mathematics question, and is more at home on Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: @brasshat: Yes I am asking about a blender add on to do this and hence asked here.